# Certificate Storage in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssl, python-requests, google-cloud-storage

I'm using the requests library in python to make https requests to a server I have, but I'm having a problem with integrating this into my Google App Engine app.

I'm using git to deploy but I don't want to store the x509 certificate in git because I don't believe certification files belong in version control.

I was looking at storing the cert in Google's Cloud Storage but from what I can find any http request sending library requires a file path to the cert.  This doesn't seem to be possible as access to the files in Cloud Storage seems to be through a REST API.

Does anyone know how to store a certificate client side like this?  Or if there is some development version of requests that supports passing certs as strings?

Comment: Which python library are you using? Are you making such requests from an App Engine application ?

Comment: I'm using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library, and yes the requests are being made from inside the App Engine application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around the problem. I put the .pem file in the project directory and added the extension to the .gitignore.  Then I can just use the other deployment method:

```
~/google_appengine/appcfg.py update my/app/location
```

Google wasn't my only repository so this isn't a problem to stop using push to deploy.